# how to change a Jacobs Landscape poster in latex from size A0 to size A4?

Tags: beamerposter

I am using a beamer template to create a poster, but its in size A0 and I need it in A4 size. Can anyone tell me how to change it please?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I would just prepare the poster as A0 but scale it to A4 when printing.

Comment: I need to submit it online as an A4 poster. I'm not actually printing it off.

Comment: What about setting up for printing to A4 and then choosing print to file?

Comment: Although changing the paper size to A4 is easy, making everything fit on such a small page will be challenging. This is because the sizes of poster elements (fonts, blocks, etc.) are mostly hard coded into the style files.

Comment: How about preparing the poster in A0, then creating a new A4 Document and include the poster there with `pdfpages`? If this is not what you want to do, please add a MWE